# PHP и строковые ключи массива

Tags: php

Есть задача написать код, в котором будет существовать массив со строковым ключом `'0'` (пишу тест на уникальную идентификацию переменной, хочу прогнать сравнение `[1, 2, 3]` и `['0' => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]`). Проблема в том, что я не могу этого добиться, потому что PHP кастует целочисленно-подобные ключи в целочисленные (во всяком случае, в PHP 5.5.9). Как заставить PHP создать такой массив (или есть ли доказательства, что такого массива не может существовать в природе)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой массив не может существовать в природе.

Вот выдержка из **[мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)**

> Строки, содержащие целое число будут
>   преобразованы к типу integer.
>   Например, ключ со значением "8" будет
>   в действительности сохранен со
>   значением 8. С другой стороны,
>   значение "08" не будет преобразовано,
>   так как оно не является корректным
>   десятичным целым.

Поведение PHP в данном случае похоже (но не идентично) на поведение javascript:

```
foo = { '10' : 'bar' };

foo['10']; // "bar"
foo[10]; // "bar"
foo[012]; // "bar"
foo['012']; // undefined!
```

Дополнительно брал информацию отсюда: **[A numeric string as array key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100488/a-numeric-string-as-array-key-in-php)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{'1'} = 'foo';
var_dump((array)$obj);
```

может

```
array(1) { ["1"]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/4TJrMO - похоже, работает :)